# Speed up/optimize CoreData code

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I am synching data from SQL Server to iPad. Data comes in XML. size of data is 7.18MB.  Pulling data is fast a few seconds but I have to populate my CoreData DB walking the XML.  Currently it takes 21 minutes to insert the data and all relationships in CoreData.  I would like to improve this and have done a number of things:

1. Use @autoreleasepool
2. Save each chunk to CoreData or Save all at once
3. Use separate ManagedObjectContext from the main one
4. Set setUndoManager to nil for that ManagedObjectContext

I am wondering if anyone can suggest any improvements.  One thing I would like to void is anymore threading than I am already doing as that causes as much issues as it solves.

4 methods shown.  First gets data, second goes through the XML and processes main child nodes, third saves context and the last one is one of the child node processing methods but is the method with the most data taking over 80 of the whole time.

Thanks in advance

```
    - (void) performFullSync {
    @autoreleasepool {
        [Common LogInfo:@"Begin" ForClass:NSStringFromClass([self class]) withSelector:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
        AFPromoPortalHTTPClient *myClient = [AFPromoPortalHTTPClient sharedClient];

        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
        AccountManager *am = appDelegate.accountManager;

        if (appDelegate.syncInProgress) {
            return;
        }

        appDelegate.syncInProgress = YES;

        if (am != nil) {
            NSString *urlMethodWithParameters = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"GetFullSyncData?accountManagerId=%@", am.userId];

            [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Daten werden synchronisiert."];

            [myClient getPath:urlMethodWithParameters parameters:nil
                      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {
                          @autoreleasepool {
                              NSString *responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseObject encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

                              // Create a background thread to process the XML data
                              dispatch_queue_t queue = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
                              dispatch_async(queue, ^{
                                  [self processSyncData:responseString];
                              });
                          }
                      }
                      failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
                          dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                              [Common LogError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error calling GetFullSyncData webservice: %@",[error localizedDescription]] ForClass:NSStringFromClass([self class]) withSelector:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
                              NSLog(@"Daten konnte nicht synchronisiert werden: %@ ", error.userInfo);

                              [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Daten konnte nicht synchronisiert werden..."];
                          });

                          [self closeSyncProgress];
                      }];
        }
        [Common LogInfo:@"End" ForClass:NSStringFromClass([self class]) withSelector:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
    }
}

- (void) processSyncData: (NSString *)data {
    [Common LogInfo:@"Begin" ForClass:NSStringFromClass([self class]) withSelector:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
    if (data.length != 0) {
        // Create context on background thread
        AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

        self.syncManagedObjectContext = [[NSManagedObjectContext alloc] init];
        [self.syncManagedObjectContext setUndoManager:nil];
        [self.syncManagedObjectContext setPersistentStoreCoordinator: [appDelegate persistentStoreCoordinator]];
        [appDelegate registerContextDidSaveNotificationForManagedObjectContext:self.syncManagedObjectContext];

        [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Daten werden geladen."];

        NSError *__autoreleasing* error = nil;

        //data = [data xmlSimpleUnescapeString];

        data = [data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&lt;" withString:@"<"];
        data = [data stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"&gt;" withString:@">"];


        // Read the full XML data
        TBXML *tbxmlFullData = [TBXML newTBXMLWithXMLString: data error: error];

        if (error == nil) {
            // Get the root node
            TBXMLElement *rtNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"rt" parentElement:tbxmlFullData.rootXMLElement];

            if(rtNode != nil) {
                @autoreleasepool {
                    // Process pricelist types
                    [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Preislisten werden geladen. Vielen Dank für Ihre Geduld..."];

                    TBXMLElement *priceListTypeNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"plts" parentElement:rtNode];
                    if (priceListTypeNode != nil) {
                        priceListTypeNode = priceListTypeNode->firstChild;
                        [self createPriceListTypeFromNode:priceListTypeNode inMOC:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
                    }
                    [self saveAndClearContext];
                }

                @autoreleasepool {
                    // Process products
                    [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Produktdaten werden geladen. Vielen Dank für Ihre Geduld..."];

                    TBXMLElement *productsNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"ps" parentElement:rtNode];
                    if (productsNode != nil) {
                        productsNode = productsNode->firstChild;
                        [self createProductsFromNode:productsNode inMOC:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
                    }
                    [self saveAndClearContext];
                }

                @autoreleasepool {
                    // Process promotions
                    [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Förderungdaten werden geladen. Vielen Dank für Ihre Geduld..."];

                    TBXMLElement *promotionsNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"prs" parentElement:rtNode];
                    if (promotionsNode != nil) {
                        promotionsNode = promotionsNode->firstChild;
                        [self createPromotionsFromNode:promotionsNode inMOC:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
                    }
                    [self saveAndClearContext];
                }

                @autoreleasepool {
                    // Process promotion products
                    [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Promotion-Produkte werden geladen. Vielen Dank für Ihre Geduld..."];

                    TBXMLElement *promotionProductsNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"pps" parentElement:rtNode];
                    if (promotionProductsNode != nil) {
                        promotionProductsNode = promotionProductsNode->firstChild;
                        [self createPromotionAndProductRelationshipFromNode:promotionProductsNode inMOC:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
                    }
                    [self saveAndClearContext];
                }

                @autoreleasepool {
                    // Process customers
                    [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Kundendaten werden geladen. Vielen Dank für Ihre Geduld..."];

                    TBXMLElement *customerNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"cs" parentElement:rtNode];
                    if (customerNode != nil) {
                        customerNode = customerNode->firstChild;
                        [self createCustomersFromNode:customerNode inMOC:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
                    }
                    [self saveAndClearContext];
                }

                @autoreleasepool {
                    // Process standard prices
                    [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Listenpreise werden geladen. Vielen Dank für Ihre Geduld..."];

                    TBXMLElement *standardPriceNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"spps" parentElement:rtNode];
                    if (standardPriceNode != nil) {
                        standardPriceNode = standardPriceNode->firstChild;
                        [self createStandardPricesFromNode:standardPriceNode inMOC:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
                    }
                    [self saveAndClearContext];
                }

                // Process sales history
                //                if (self.syncType == StartUpSync) {
                //                    // Process product sales history
                //                    TBXMLElement *productSalesHistoryNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"sh" parentElement:rtNode];
                //                    if (productSalesHistoryNode != nil) {
                //                        productSalesHistoryNode = productSalesHistoryNode->firstChild;
                //                        [self createProductSalesHistoryFromNode:productSalesHistoryNode inMOC:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
                //                    }
                //                }

                @autoreleasepool {
                    // Process Order Statuses
                    [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Auftragsstatus wird geladen. Vielen Dank für Ihre Geduld..."];

                    TBXMLElement *orderStatusNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"oss" parentElement:rtNode];
                    if (orderStatusNode != nil) {
                        orderStatusNode = orderStatusNode->firstChild;
                        [self createOrderStatusesFromNode:orderStatusNode inMOC:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
                    }
                    [self saveAndClearContext];
                }

                @autoreleasepool {
                    // Process order
                    [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Aufträge werden geladen. Vielen Dank für Ihre Geduld..."];

                    TBXMLElement *orderNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"os" parentElement:rtNode];
                    if (orderNode != nil) {
                        orderNode = orderNode->firstChild;
                        [self createOrdersFromNode:orderNode inMOC:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
                    }
                    [self saveAndClearContext];
                }

                @autoreleasepool {
                    // Process customer prices
                    [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Kundenpreise werden geladen. Vielen Dank für Ihre Geduld..."];

                    TBXMLElement *customerPriceNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"cpps" parentElement:rtNode];
                    if (customerPriceNode != nil) {
                        customerPriceNode = customerPriceNode->firstChild;
                        [self createCustomerPricesFromNode:customerPriceNode inMOC:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
                    }
                    [self saveAndClearContext];
                }

                NSDate *lsd;
                // Read the saver last synced date
                TBXMLElement *lastSyncDateNode = [TBXML childElementNamed:@"sd" parentElement:rtNode];
                if (lastSyncDateNode != nil) {
                    lastSyncDateNode = lastSyncDateNode->firstChild;
                    lsd = [self getDateFromString:[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"date" forElement:lastSyncDateNode] ];
                    NSLog(@"%@",lsd);
                }
                // Save the context.
                NSError *error = nil;
                [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Daten werden auf Ihrem iPad gespeichert."];
                if (![self.syncManagedObjectContext save:&error]) {
                    NSLog(@"\nFehler! Daten konnten nicht auf Ihrem iPad gespeichert werden: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                    [Common LogError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error saving data: %@",[error localizedDescription]] ForClass:NSStringFromClass([self class]) withSelector:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];

                    [self closeSyncProgress];
                }
                else {
                    [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:@"Synchronisation abgeschlossen."];
                    [Common updateLastSynchedDate:lsd];

                    if (self.syncType!=StartUpSync) {
                        [self processPendingOrdersinMOC:self.syncManagedObjectContext];
                    }
                    else
                        [self closeSyncProgress];
                }
            }
            else
                [self closeSyncProgress];
        }
    }else
        [self closeSyncProgress];


    [Common LogInfo:@"End" ForClass:NSStringFromClass([self class]) withSelector:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
}

-(void)saveAndClearContext{
    NSError *error = nil;
    if (![self.syncManagedObjectContext save:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"\nFehler! Daten konnten nicht auf Ihrem iPad gespeichert werden: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
        [Common LogError:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Error saving data: %@",[error localizedDescription]] ForClass:NSStringFromClass([self class]) withSelector:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
    }
    else {
        [self.syncManagedObjectContext reset];
    }
}

- (void) createCustomerPricesFromNode: (TBXMLElement*)customerPriceNode inMOC: (NSManagedObjectContext*) moc {
    [Common LogInfo:@"Begin" ForClass:NSStringFromClass([self class]) withSelector:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
    CustomerPrice *newCustomerPrice = nil;
    Customer *c = nil;

    while(customerPriceNode != nil) {
        if (self.syncType == StartUpSync)
            newCustomerPrice = (CustomerPrice *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CustomerPrice" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
        else
        {
            // Incremental sync
            NSNumber *customerPriceId = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"id" forElement:customerPriceNode] intValue]];
            NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"customerPriceId == %i", [customerPriceId intValue]];
            newCustomerPrice = (CustomerPrice *)[Common getEntityWithName:@"CustomerPrice" usingPredicate:pred inManagedObjectContext:moc];

            // New CustomerPrice found during Incremental sync
            if (newCustomerPrice == nil) {
                newCustomerPrice = (CustomerPrice *)[NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"CustomerPrice" inManagedObjectContext:moc];
            }
        }

        if (newCustomerPrice != nil) {
            newCustomerPrice.customerPriceId = [NSNumber numberWithInt: [[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"id" forElement:customerPriceNode] intValue]];
            newCustomerPrice.validFrom = [self getDateFromString:[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"vF" forElement:customerPriceNode]];
            newCustomerPrice.validTo = [self getDateFromString:[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"vT" forElement:customerPriceNode]];
            newCustomerPrice.price = [NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"pr" forElement:customerPriceNode]];
            newCustomerPrice.enabled =[NSNumber numberWithBool: [[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"en" forElement:customerPriceNode] boolValue]];
            newCustomerPrice.deleted =[NSNumber numberWithBool: [[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"del" forElement:customerPriceNode] boolValue]];

            // Get Customer and Product and associate them with customer price
            NSNumber *cId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"cRef" forElement:customerPriceNode] intValue]];
            NSNumber *pId = [NSNumber numberWithInt:[[TBXML valueOfAttributeNamed:@"pRef" forElement:customerPriceNode] intValue]];

            [self updateUIProgressLabelWithText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Kundenpreise werden geladen.  Vielen Dank für Ihre Geduld.  \nKunde: %@.  Produkt: %@.", cId, pId]];

            if (c == nil || [c.customerId intValue] != [cId intValue]) {
                if (newCustomerPrice.customerPriceCustomer == nil) {
                    NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"customerId == %i", [cId intValue]];
                    c = (Customer *)[Common getEntityWithName:@"Customer" usingPredicate:pred inManagedObjectContext:moc];
                    newCustomerPrice.customerPriceCustomer = c;
                }
            }
            else {
                newCustomerPrice.customerPriceCustomer = c;
            }

            if (newCustomerPrice.customerPriceProduct == nil) {
                NSPredicate *pred = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat: @"productId == %i", [pId intValue]];
                Product *p = (Product *)[Common getEntityWithName:@"Product" usingPredicate:pred inManagedObjectContext:moc];
                newCustomerPrice.customerPriceProduct = p;
            }

            customerPriceNode = [TBXML nextSiblingNamed:@"cpp" searchFromElement:customerPriceNode];
        }
    }
    [Common LogInfo:@"End" ForClass:NSStringFromClass([self class]) withSelector:NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)];
}
```

================ SLOW METHODS =================

```
21%
-(NSDate *) getDateFromString:(NSString *)dateString
{
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];

    if ([dateString rangeOfString:@"."].location == NSNotFound) {
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"];
    }
    else
        [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.zzz"];

    //    [dateFormat setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    [dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithName:@"GMT"]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

    return date;
}

61%
+ (NSManagedObject*) getEntityWithName: (NSString*)entityName usingPredicate: (NSPredicate*) predicate inManagedObjectContext: (NSManagedObjectContext*) moc {

    NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:entityName inManagedObjectContext:moc];
    request.entity = entity;    
    request.predicate = predicate;

    NSError *error = nil;
    NSMutableArray *mutableFetchResults = [[moc executeFetchRequest:request error:&error] mutableCopy];
    if (mutableFetchResults == nil || mutableFetchResults.count < 1 ) {
        return nil;
    }
    else
    {
        return [mutableFetchResults objectAtIndex:0];
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you used Instruments to profile your app, determining what (primarily) is taking so long? Just skimming code and looking for spots to optimize is not a very effective strategy.

Comment: I have Craig, In fact all synching except that method with the huge data takes 30 seconds! That method is running through 60k XML elements each becoming a core Data object and then establishing its relationship using predicate to query DB.  I cannot see anything particularly wrong.  Just a lot of data

Comment: Right, that makes sense - but *what* in that "method with the huge data" is taking so long? Is it the creation of the `TBXML`? The processing? A particular piece of the processing? Saying, "It's this one method here" doesn't really give you (or us) any clues as to how it can be optimized.

Comment: I just removed the bit that creates the relationships and that brought speed down to 6 minutes!  So the whole method takes 20 minutes, the relationships creation takes 14 minutes.  So from that info and concentrating on that method only can you see any improvement that can be made?

Comment: Please take some time to read about Instruments, the profiling tool included with Xcode, and try using it to pinpoint *exactly where* you're spending time: http://www.raywenderlich.com/23037/how-to-use-instruments-in-xcode

Comment: OK will do and report back my findings.  Thank you

Comment: That was the best advice I ever had here.  Things look much clearer now.  There are 2 methods taking most of the time.  I show them below.  One simply takes a date string from my xml and returns date and the other queries the retrieves a CoreData object given a predicate (not sure why I am using NSMutableArray there to be honest!)

Comment: Depending on how your date string looks, I've had *really* good success in the past writing my own `SimpleDate` class that parses quickly into a few `int` primitives, and lazily will return an `NSDate` if queried for one.

Comment: My date is like this 2014-06-09T11:21:15.180 but sometimes without the .180 which you will see I am dealing with in the method - I updated the question showing the slow methods

Comment: 1. Avoid creating `NSDateFormatter` every time. It’s very slow, so cache it. Prior to iOS 6 you must also create `NSDateFormatter` for every thread which uses it. From iOS 7 it’s thread safe and one instance is enough for all threads. 2. `getEntityForName` - why you are copying results from NSFetchRequest? Use Instruments as others already wrote.

Comment: Thom_ek, thank you.  Before seeing your comment here I saw on Apple docs that NSDateFormatter is expensive and I realised that I was actually created 120k of them when synching my data!! I created a static instance and that brought speed from 6 minutes to 40 seconds!! For getEntityWithName I only realised what I was doing when I tried to post this question and it is now back to normal NSArray as I need to make only one object is returned.  is there a better way?